# Display a component's template in App.vue

Tags: templates, vue.js, components

I have a component, Header.vue, and I want to display it in the main application, App.vue.
This is the Header

```js
<script>
</script>
```

```html
<template>
  <div> 
      Some text
  <div>
</template>
```

And this is the App.vue

```js
<script>
import Header from "./components/views/Header.vue"
export default {

}
</script>
```

```html
<template>
  <div id="app">
    <Header>
  </div>
</template>
```

Can someone please tell me what I'm doing wrong?
Thanks in advance

Comment: You need to declare the component in your `export default { components: {Footer: Footer} }`

Comment: Thanks, it worked

Answer (score 0):

```js
<template>
    <div id="app">
        <app-header></app-header>
    </div>
</template>


<script>
    import Header from "./components/views/Header.vue"
    export default {
        components: {
        appHeader: Header,
        }
    }
</script>
```